# Error Don't know how to build task 'run'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

me sale este error al momento de ejecutar mi servidor de ruby:

```
$ rails run
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'run' (see --tasks)
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:14:in `block in run_rake_task'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:11:in `run_rake_task'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.0.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:51:in `run_command!'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/railties-
5.0.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
/home/daniel/Documentos/RedRuby/backend-2016/bin/rails:9:in `require'
/home/daniel/Documentos/RedRuby/backend-2016/bin/rails:9:in `<top 
(required)>'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in ` 
<top (required)>'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
/home/daniel/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/spring-
2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
/home/daniel/Documentos/RedRuby/backend-2016/bin/spring:13:in ` 
require'
/home/daniel/Documentos/RedRuby/backend-2016/bin/spring:13:in `<top 
(required)>'
bin/rails:3:in `load'
bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

mi version de ruby es **2.3.0** y de rails lo tenia en **5.0.0.beta2** pero se cambio, al momento de hacer bundle update, a la version **5.0.6**

resumiendo, como podria correr mi servidor ya que no me deja

Comment: Te recomiendo que veas algún tutorial de rails. Eso es parte de lo básico

Comment: lo se pero no se porque se me olvido ese comando tan basico...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El comando `run` es incorrecto (no existe en *Rails*), para iniciar el servidor de *Rails* debes utilizar el comando `server`:

```
$ rails server
```

O bien, puedes utilizar simplemente `s`:

```
$ rails s
```

Comment: me pdie que debo hacer una migracion, como podria realizarla?

Comment: @daniel `rails db:migrate`, esto creará las tablas en tu base de datos.

Comment: una ultima duda, tengo mi server alojado localmente, si quiero ponerlo a que funcione con no-ip o ip publica en donde puedo acomodar la ip con la que se inicial el server

Comment: @daniel la respuesta de gerry cumple con lo que preguntaste,así que podrías marcarla como aceptada. Si tienes otras dudas que no estén relacionadas con lo que preguntaste, deberías plantearlas en una nueva pregunta.